# Thunderbolt Bridge Mode: compatible to RTP-MIDI/ multicast UDP

Tags: thunderbolt, midi

When a Thunderbolt bridge is established as a network with fixed IPs between two Macs, does it support with its emulation a standard ethernet connection in terms of RTP-MIDI and multicast UDP data transmission?

Answer (score 0):

The Thunderbolt Bridge is not a standard Ethernet connection, but macOS provides you with an IP interface where you can send IP packets between two computers.

RTP-MIDI is a protocol that encapsulates MIDI messages within RTP packets that are exchanged over the UDP protocol. The UDP protocol runs on top of the IP protocol, and as such RTP-MIDI is fully compatible with Thunderbolt Bridge connections.

Similarly multicast UDP runs on top of the IP protocol and as such is fully compatible with Thunderbolt Bridge connections. Obviously its usefulness is not quite the same here, as you normally use multicasting to send the same data to many hosts on the network at the same time. As a Thunderbolt Bridge connection is always between two computers, and two computers only, the multicast element is not really the same.

Comment: So in this case i dont understand why i encounter huge midi transfer problems such as syncing the host to midi clock, or problems with apps like ipmidi/audiogridder and similar. to clarify: these apps are working perfectly with a „real“ ethernet connection.

Comment: Well, why didn’t you ask a question about that then?  Detail the problems you’re having in a new question, and we can look at that.

Comment: Ok sorry my fault. not so familiar with the site rules yet. problem is: two macs connected via tb bridge with unique ip each. wifi/internet are disabled on both. with the apps ipmidi/rtp midi/audiogridder i can play them on the host mac ( in logic/ableton/bitwig), but as soon i hit the play/record button on the master mac, there are distorted and sync failures when i hit the keys on my masterkeyboards as ic if the midi beat clock signals are interfering with regular midi note transmissions. this problem doesnt appear in a ethernet network setup with regular ethernet cable interconnections